# Wrapping ETH into WETH via ethers -- WETH coins on my balance won't appear

Tags: transactions, tokens, ethers.js, contract-invocation, wrapped-tokens

I'm attempting to wrap ETH on Goerli into WETH by calling `deposit` function using ethers. Even though several TX already have **been confirmed and successfully mined**, nothing will appear on my WETH balance at `goerli.etherscan.io` in the dropdown `Token Holdings`. There's not even `WETH` there at all, whereas there're other tokens

```
  async function myWrap(prKey) {
    let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(prKey, provider);
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(WETH_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, WETH_ABI, wallet);
    const txSigner = contract.connect(wallet);

    const balance = await provider.getBalance(wallet.address);
    const gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice();
    const balanceMinusGas = balance.sub(gasPrice.mul(ETH_GAS_LIMIT));

    let tx = txSigner.deposit({value: amountToSend});
    return tx;
  }
```

What's the matter?

Moreover, at `https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2` my TX-s are present.

Answer (score 1):

The address you're using for WETH (0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2) is the address on Ethereum mainnet. Notice on the goerli etherscan page for that address, there's no `contract` tab. That's because this isn't a smart contract, just a regular address. Attempting to deposit ETH to that address on Goerli will just transfer your Goerlie ETH to that wallet

The correct contract to use for WETH on Goerli is https://goerli.etherscan.io/token/0xb4fbf271143f4fbf7b91a5ded31805e42b2208d6

Comment: How have you found out that `0xb4fbf271143f4fbf7b91a5ded31805e42b2208d6` is the correct one on Goerli?

Comment: even with this address, no WETH will be transfered to my address. As if a step was missing in my code. What could it be?